# Good example of using enums for conditional rendering in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking into good practices for conditional rendering in React, and I really like the ENUM pattern, but I'm looking for some good examples of it being used. The [tutorials](https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react) I found are a bit too simplistic/short, I'd like to see a more fleshed out example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you would count this as the exact same pattern but seeing noone else has added anything this is where I usually get the most use out of a similar concept.

Assume you have a list of data that contains objects with a `type` property that has a set number of known values, lets say `'Car' | 'Boat' | 'Plane'`.

Now you want to display these objects to the user, but the views for each type is vastly different, this is one of the instances where the ENUM pattern can help.

**Example: Component Mapping**

```
const data = [
    {
        type: 'Car',
        uniqueCarProperty: 'I am a unique car property'
    },
    {
        type: 'Boat',
        uniqueBoatProperty: 'I am a unique boat property'
    },
    {
        type: 'Plane',
        uniquePlaneProperty: 'I am a unique plane property'
    },
    {
        type: 'Tractor',
        uniqueTractorProperty: 'I am a unique tractor property'
    }
];

// Component for view unique to vehicles of type 'Car'
const CarComponent = ({ uniqueCarProperty }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            Car: {uniqueCarProperty}
        </div>
    );
}

// Component for view unique to vehicles of type 'Boat'
const BoatComponent = ({ uniqueBoatProperty }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            Boat: {uniqueBoatProperty}
        </div>
    );
}

// Component for view unique to vehicles of type 'Plane'
const PlaneComponent = ({ uniquePlaneProperty }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            Plane: {uniquePlaneProperty}
        </div>
    );
}

// Component mapping used to link vehicle type to appropriate view.
// Property name must match type value (case sensitive)
const componentMapping = {
    Car: CarComponent,
    Boat: BoatComponent,
    Plane: PlaneComponent
}

const ExampleComponent = ({ vehicles }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {vehicles && vehicles.map((v, i) => {
                // retrieve type from vehicle data.
                const { type, ...props } = v;

                // get component mapping using type.
                const Component = componentMapping[type];

                // handle unknown types
                if (!Component) {
                    return (
                        <div key={i}>Unsupported vehicle type: {type}</div>
                    )
                }

                // render mapped component
                // all vehicle data except type is provided to the component as props.
                return (
                    <Component key={i} {...props} />
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
};

const App = ({}) => {
    return (
        <ExampleComponent vehicles={data} />
    )
}
```

The component mapping doesn't have to remain a constant external to the component. It could be passed in as a prop or constructed within the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

An "enum" (it's really more a dictionary or a map) is exactly the same as a switch statement or a condition structure-wise. It's improving readability because it is an expression and not as statement, which is good, but that is all.

Of all the techniques explained in the article, higher level components is the only one that can actually help you design your view logic.

By the way, the "nested" conditionals in the article are not nested, they are simply a sequence of if, else if and else. You can recognise a nested ternary when you have a sequence of two or more adjacent `?`.